# making the gif start from the begining after closing and reopening it

Tags: flutter, dart, gif

I am trying to make this gif appears when clicking on the floating action button and popint it again after pressing on ok:
    https://66.media.tumblr.com/1ce23970665b7736bd857720ebf5a5b2/tumblr_pp3sftPVIy1wb1n5x_540.gif
The problem is that when I click ok and reclick the floating action button, the gif continue from it stopped last time I pressed ok; I want it to start from the begining every time I click the floating action button. How can I do this? Here's the code:

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.healing),

          onPressed: () {
            showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (_) => Container(
                height: 200.0,
                child: NetworkGiffyDialog(
                  // key: keys[1],
                  image: Image.network(
                    gif,
                    fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                  ),
                  title: Text("Exercises of breathing"),
                  description: Text(
                    'This will help you with breathing exercises to overcome anxiety attacks',
                  ),
                  entryAnimation: EntryAnimation.RIGHT,
                  onOkButtonPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
          //child: new Text("Breathing exercise"),
        ),
```

**EDIT**: I followed the first answer and tried to switch between null value and the gif link as follows, however i still have the same problem

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.healing),

          onPressed: () {
            setState(() => gif = giflink);
            showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (_) => Container(
                height: 200.0,
                child: NetworkGiffyDialog(
                  // key: keys[1],
                  image: Image.network(
                    gif,
                    fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                  ),
                  title: Text("Exercises of breathing"),
                  description: Text(
                    'This will help you with breathing exercises to overcome anxiety attacks',
                  ),
                  entryAnimation: EntryAnimation.RIGHT,
                  onOkButtonPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    setState(() => gif = null);
                  },
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
          //child: new Text("Breathing exercise"),
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try is using your variable `gif` as setState a null value to it after the animation (GIF duration) ends (or if user cancels).

```
var gif = "https://theurlofyourgif.com/file.gif"

void doYourGIFLogic() {
  // show it with a Navigator, or Opacity, or Visibility, etc
  // wait for that animation (GIF duration) to be done
  final NetworkImage provider = NetworkImage(gif);
  provider.evict().then<void>((bool success) {
  if (success) {
    print('removed image!');
  }
});
}
```

When the user clicks again using the FAB, the cache will be cleared and the GIF should start from the beginning.

Comment: thank you so much for your reply. i did so, but the problem is still there.

Comment: @Mee check my updated response. Look like Image.network cache the file and you need to "evict" it to clear the cache and make it run again like if it was the first time.